# form_for details not displaying in view :Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am using simple form_for to create new object but on the ads/new.html.erb on h1 tag is displayed but form's information is missing

Here is my new.html.erb file contents

```
<h1>New Ad</h1>
<% form_for(@ad ,:url=>{:action=>'create',method: :post}) do |f| %>
<p>
<b>Name:</b> <%= f.text_field:name %>
</p>
<p>
<b>Description:</b><%= f.text_area:description %>
</p>
<p>
<b>Price:</b><%= f.text_field:price %>
</p>
<p>
<b>Seller Id:</b><%= f.text_field:seller_id %>
</p>
<p>
<b>Email Address:</b><%= f.text_field:email %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit "Create Ad" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
<% form_for(@ad ,:url=>{:action=>'create',method: :post}) do |f| %>
```

should be like this

```
<%= form_for(@ad ,:url=>{:action=>'create',method: :post}) do |f| %>
```

You are missing `=` sign

Reference,see the **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)**

**Additional note**

I guess you can refactor it to

```
<%= form_for(@ad) do |f| %>
```